# docker postgres cant connect on non standart ports forward

Tags: docker

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  database:
    container_name: proj-database
    env_file: ../orm/.env.${PROJ_ENV}
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5433
    ports:
     - 5432:5432
     - 5433:5432
    networks:
      - proj
```

I can connect from other containers with `5432`, but i can't from other containers connect with `5433`. Whats the problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to expose the same port on the container with two ports on the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connections between containers always use the "normal" port number for the destination service.  They don't consider any remappings in `ports:`; in fact, they don't need `ports:` at all.  `ports:` are only used for connections from outside Docker into a container.  Conversely, since internally each container has its own private IP address, there aren't conflicts even if you are running multiple copies of the same image.

Comment: I just wanted to add that you can access containers inner IP(within other container), by using the name of the service(ex. in my case name of the container is `database` and just use it as `database:5432`).